# Xcode Animations complete instantly - CAAnimations call didStop - flag = FALSE

Tags: objective-c, animation

I'm getting some weird bugs.  I thought I had a handle on this.  I copied code from one of my other projects.  I'm wondering if it could be something to do with my custom class.

I have a view controller initialize my custom class called "TitleCardView"

Inside there I have a bunch of animations like this one:

```
CGPoint startPointb = borderMaskLayer.position;
    CGPoint endPointb = CGPointMake(borderMaskLayer.position.x, borderMaskLayer.position.y-1000);
    CABasicAnimation* bmoveAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    bmoveAnim.delegate=self;
    [bmoveAnim setValue:@"borderMaskAnim1" forKey:@"id"];
    bmoveAnim.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:startPointb];
    bmoveAnim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:endPointb];
    bmoveAnim.duration = 1;
    [bmoveAnim setBeginTime:CACurrentMediaTime()+.4];
    bmoveAnim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    bmoveAnim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    bmoveAnim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
    [self.borderLayer.mask addAnimation:bmoveAnim forKey:@"position"];
    [self.borderWhiteLayer.mask addAnimation:bmoveAnim forKey:@"position"];
```

The animation works fine but when I try to implement AnimationDidStop{, as soon as the view loads, all the animations get logged by the delegate method with the FALSE (did not finish) flag.

I added a button and tried to use:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:6 animations:^{
    continueButton.alpha = 1.0f;
 }];
```

and this code with the delay parameter....

Same problem.  As soon as the view loads, its like the animation gets run immediately with a duration of 0.

Are you not supposed to add animations in your init method?  I feel like there must be a rule I'm breaking that I don't know about.

This code does work:

this button is the last thing in the init method

```
continueButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [continueButton addTarget:self
                             action:@selector(titleNext)
                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [continueButton setTitle:@"Click to Continue" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    continueButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 390.0, 320.0, 75.0);
    [self addSubview:continueButton];
    continueButton.alpha = 1.0;
```

then this is the method it calls

```
-(void)titleNext{
    // proceeds to the motto page from the title page

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.6 animations:^{
        continueButton.alpha = 0.0f;
    }];

}
```

So can anyone tell me why my animations are acting weird???

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the project and found the animationDidStop delegate worked when the animations were created in -(void)viewDidAppear{ instead of -(void)viewDidLoad{

Answer (score 0):

For swift it works if the animations are in
 `override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)`